# Controlling RGB LED (common anode) with Arduino

Tags: arduino, led, rgb

I have an RGB LED ([datasheet here](http://make-documents.s3.amazonaws.com/VnlL5derD5jMI5TL.pdf)) that I want to control using an Arduino R3 ([datasheet here](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno)). How can I do this? The LED has a common anode, not a common cathode. However, the arduino's I/O pins can only be +5 volts. This is a problem, because I need to somehow hook up the LED's cathodes to the arduino's I/O pins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only a problem if you think in terms of SOURCING a current from an output. Outputs also SINK current.

[image]

When the output is set LOW current will flow INTO the pin to ground (SINKING).

Answer (score 2):

The Arduino IO pins can "output" high or low (+5v or 0v) which means you can drive a LED either direction. Generic schematic (couldn't find RGB LED in the editor):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxEC7d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>